# Which file(s) should I include in my php script to make use of functions WordPress provides?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an WordPress page that include the javascript file generated by php script (`<script src="myScript.js.php" />`).

Inside of that php script I would like to use WordPress functions like `get_category_by_slug()`, `get_posts()`, `get_option()` and so on.

But my php file does not include the WordPress "framework".

Which file(s) should I include in my php script to make use of functions WordPress provides to e.g. `archive.php` in `/theme` folder?

I've already tried to include each file from `wp-include` but it wasn't an good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bootsrap the application you only need to do two things:

1. Include the loader file `require_once( 'wp-load.php' )`
2. Start the application `wp()`

Now you have access to all the framework functions!